# What are "spiritual songs" as mentioned in Eph 5: 19?

Tags: word-study

Could any song inspired by our being "in Christ" said to be spiritual?
Or does "spiritual song" refer only to the psalms and hymns already mentioned in this verse? Perhaps "spiritual songs" are songs the Holy Spirit gives us in a situation for that moment. Or could they be like speaking in tongues v19 "melodies in your heart"? Maybe the Holy Spirit does not like to be tied down by our definitions and so we should keep an open and informed mind as to what is a spiritual song..."be filled with the Spirit; speaking to yourselves in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs, singing and making melody in your heart to the Lord". A.V.

Comment: Considering I’m asking a question on the carnal man (contrasting to the spiritual man) it should be interesting to see what a spiritual song is and how it differs to a carnal song, both composed by Christians. There is one way to sing to a baby there is another to sing to an adult. Generally adults (spiritual) tolerate baby songs (carnal) they don’t enjoy them per se. Since carnal worldly songs are now sung to some Christian lyrics in Church there is hardly any distinction or knowledge of what a spiritual song actually is anymore. It’s become a comparison between carnal in and out of church.

Comment: Psalms is clear.  However, "hymns" is usually understood as an anthem of praise to God.  The others appear to be the sort of music created by a spiritually inspired person in  much the same way that the historical church has created music through the centuries and still does.

Comment: @Mac's Musings Could singing ..in your heart be singing in tongues?

Comment: I suppose that this theoretically possible but it is not a connection that the NT makes.  Therefore, on the basis of the NT evidence, I am unwilling to make that association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Spiritual Songs

Let's hear how Jesus said it.

**John 4:24 Greek NT: Nestle 1904**

> Πνεῦμα ὁ Θεός, καὶ τοὺς προσκυνοῦντας ἐν πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ δεῖ προσκυνεῖν.

Spirit the God, and those worshiping him in spirit and truth inevitably worship.

### The Simplified Explanation

All of us stand as the image of God, and the illusion caused from our likeness in him is that we are him. I am an image, there is only one God. When turning the eyes away from the illusion of "authority", and giving him, the one true God the Authority, as is his right as the creator and source of everything. This is like ignoring the image of flesh and looking into the unseen for the spirit.

Commands coming from the mouth of me shows commands of the flesh, but commands coming from the mouth of the God show the commands of the unseen, and because we do not see him we call him the Spirit. And when the words coming from the mouth of me is the same as from the mouth of him. My image represents him because I was made in his image.

And as the image representing him I bring glory at my image. Not because this image created anything, but because others can see the God through the image.

Bring us to the challenge facing every single image. When the others see me can they see him who made everything? For the entire body strives desperately to see the mighty God. And can they see God through me?

Therefore if I sing, I must sing like God. If I walk, I must walk like God. If I talk, I must talk like God. I must be like him in EVERY WAY and EVERY MOMENT for I am his image, otherwise the spirit is just the spirit, and the body just the body.

Therefore it is on everyone in the world to be the righteousness of God, that way I can look at you and see my God, his may faces, his many personalities. And the most important one that I can see that you care for me because I care for you. And if you need some song that brings faith in my care I could sing.

However I need the people to hear me, and whoever listens has showed their care beyond any song.

### Conclusion

- Greater the listener because when speaking they will hear.
- Greater the spokesman of God because God gains the body.
- Greater the singer who cares because they will care also.
- Greater the one that sits down their project when the request comes because in time of the asking they will sit down their project and help.

### How can I tell if the Song is Spiritual?

- Does this song make the others feel like I care?
- Will they see God through me?